# Render multiple independent UI elements at once in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a Shiny dashboard with multiple UI elements that depends on different reactive values. By default Shiny renders every element as soon as it is ready, but this gives a unpleasing visual aesthetics when loading the page, especially if you have very similar elements like `valueBox` loading at different times.

My question is: is there a way to tight some UI elements together, so they will render all at once when the slowest is ready?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a minimal example?

Comment: I could, but I don't think I need to in this case.